# HTTP over multi-hop ssh

Tags: ssh-tunnel

I have access to a linux server via a multi-hop ssh

```
ssh -L3880:localhost:3880 user@first-hop-server -t ssh -L3880:localhost:3880 user@end-server
```

This is fine for access through ssh.
However I want also to access Apache web server on port 80 of the end server with a web browser.

I've found solution without hopping, but I'm not sure how to adapt it.
I'm on a MacOS machine

EDIT:
If I try Tero suggestion, and activating -v on ssh I see more or less:

```
debug1: Connection to port 3880 forwarding to localhost port 3880 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [direct-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 3880 forwarding to localhost port 3880 requested.
debug1: channel 2: new [direct-tcpip]
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 2: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 3880 for localhost port 3880, 
connect from 127.0.0.1 port 38535, nchannels 3
debug1: Connection to port 3880 forwarding to localhost port 3880 requested.
debug1: channel 4: new [direct-tcpip]
```

(it goes on on different channels/ports all refused)

Answer (score 3):

Since one Apache host can host multiple domains, you need to make sure that your browser sends the `Host` header when making a HTTP connection, or the corresponding TLS header with HTTPS.

In order to achieve this, you need to edit your `/etc/hosts` file so that it includes:

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
```

Where `example.com` is the domain you want to reach.

After that you can make an SSH tunnel like above, and open the website with `http://domain.com:port` in your browser.

Edit: You need to make the last forward to server's HTTP port 80 or HTTPS port 443.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. logs too long to put here, I'll add to question

Answer (score 2):

I modified using the second tunnel on port 80

```
ssh -L3880:localhost:3880 user@first-hop-server -t ssh -L3880:localhost:80 user@end-server
```

So I understand that, locally port:3880->first-hop:3880
And from first-hop another tunnel takes port 3880 to webserver port 80

And using Tero suggestion, I now manage to open website on http://domain.com:3880
Having defined in /etc/hosts 127.0.0.1 domain.com

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is **Jump Proxy**:

```
ssh -N -A -J user1@host1 -D 8123 user2@host2
```

then you can use `SOCKS` in local via `127.0.0.1:8123`